# jQuery wait until function ends then do it again

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var repeat = 5;

for (var i = 0; i < repeat.length; ++i)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
        url: baseUri + '?rand=' + new Date().getTime(),
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        dataType : "json",
        data: 'something_to_post=1234'),
        success: function(jsonData,textStatus,jqXHR)
        {
            //some functions
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            //some alert code
        }
    });
}
```

So this loop will repeat 2 times and will make 2 request at the same time, so my question is, how do I delay it , when first loop is done...move to second loop.

Thank you

Comment: I'm guessing it's a typo here, but just in case it's not - you have a close bracket at the end of the line where you set data ;)

Comment: I don't understand why loop will make only two requests .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got to think in terms of callbacks. You have a task - making an AJAX call - and you want to do it again after the AJAX call finishes. Put the task into a function, and then call that function from the `success` callback of the AJAX call. To keep track of the number of repeats, pass it into the function as an explicit variable:

```
function makeCalls(numCalls) {
    if (numCalls <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
        url: baseUri + '?rand=' + new Date().getTime(),
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        dataType : "json",
        data: 'something_to_post=1234'),
        success: function(jsonData,textStatus,jqXHR)
        {
            //some functions

            //make the next call
            makeCalls(numCalls - 1);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            //some alert code
        }
    });
}
makeCalls(5);
```

The way I wrote it here, it won't make the next call if there's an error, but it's up to you what you want to do in that case.

Comment: Good answer.  I think you have an off by 1 indexing problem, though.  makeCall(1) will make 2 calls, won't it?  The first call, then 1 > 0 so it will make a second call.

Comment: @MikeEdwards: oh true. the number right now means "the number of times to do it after this one". I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use recursive function.

```
function callme(){
if(i<5){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
        url: baseUri + '?rand=' + new Date().getTime(),
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        dataType : "json",
        data: 'something_to_post=1234'),
        success: function(jsonData,textStatus,jqXHR)
        {
            callme();
i++;
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            //some alert code
        }
    });}
}
```

Comment: oh god. you really don't want to use `i` as a global variable here do you?

Comment: ya i is global variable. you can reset it to zero once you finish with that. I posted just concept... :)

Comment: i getit.. but it's going to fail horribly when you happen to have a for loop in your global scope.. really suggest the way i did it of passing it in as a variable